# Using Susy's isolate-grid() at multiple breakpoints

Tags: susy-compass

I'm trying to use different `isolate-grid()` settings at multiple breakpoints like so:

Markup:

```
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box">
    Box 1
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    Box 2
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    Box 3
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    Box 4
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    Box 5
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    Box 6
  </div>
</div>
```

SASS:

```
$total-columns: 4;
$column-width: 60px;
$gutter-width: 40px;
$grid-padding: $gutter-width / 2;
$container-style: fluid;
$container-width: 940px;

%container {
  $include container;

    @include at-breakpoint(9) {
      @include set-container-width;
    }

    @include at-breakpoint(12) {
      @include set-container-width;
    }
}

.boxes
  @extend %container;

  .box {
    @include isolate-grid(2);

    @include at-breakpoint(9) {
      @include isolate-grid(3,9);
    }

    @include at-breakpoint(12) {
      @include isolate-grid(4,12);
    }
  }
}
```

However, even though the column spans adjust as expected, the omegas don't seem to get reset correctly and so some of the boxes get cleared and don't appear on the same row.

I'm sure I've missed something obvious, but I've been going round in circles for ages now!  I've tried adding in various combinations of `reset-omega()` and `reset-columns()` but no joy as yet.

Any ideas to put me out of my misery?!

Regards,

Matt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really good point. You should be able to simply add a `clear: none;` override using the right nth-selector at the next breakpoint. Susy uses the format `Xn + 1` where "X" is the number of items in a row. In your case this should do it:

```
.boxes {
  @extend %container;

  .box {
    @include isolate-grid(2);

    @include at-breakpoint(9) {
      // 2n + 1 because the smaller grid had 2 items in each row
      &:nth-child(2n + 1) { clear: none; }
      @include isolate-grid(3,9);
    }

    @include at-breakpoint(12) {
      // no override needed, because the smaller grid also had 3 per row
      @include isolate-grid(4,12);
    }
  }
}
```

It's actually a bit tricky to determine how we would "fix" that in Susy, but you're right to bring it up - we should certainly look for a cleaner solution. Would you mind filing an issue on GitHub? Thanks!

Comment: Many thanks Eric, I'll give that a try.  Issue filed on GitHub :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the workaround Brett, it's similar to what I was using before I tried `isolate-grid()`, however I was doing it like this (which I believe achieves the same thing):

```
.box {
  @include span-columns(2);
  @include nth-omega(2n); // every second item completes a row.

  @include at-breakpoint(9) {
    @include span-columns(3,9);
    @include remove-nth-omega(2n);
    @include nth-omega(3n); // every third item completes a row.
  }

  @include at-breakpoint(12) {
    @include span-columns(4,12);
    @include remove-nth-omega(2n);
    @include nth-omega(3n); // every third item completes a row.
  }
}
```

Interested to know which way is more efficient/preferable, or if they both compile to identical CSS?

Comment: This is a reply to [BrettUX's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16308573/250775) but I wasn't sure the correct way to make a reply and include code? I realise now that if either answer is up/downvoted then the flow will lose context, but I couldn't post sufficient code in a comment - any advise for a new user gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a bug with isolate-grid(). I have isolated the issue to being that the first isolate-grid() call applies a clear: left; to the ending items of the row.

However, trying to add clear: none; at the next breakpoint, before the next isolate-grid() call did absolutely nothing.

I had to go back to nth-child declarations until they can fix this bug. In case anyone needs a workaround, this is how you would do this with nth-child selectors:

```
.box {
  @include span-columns(2);

  @include at-breakpoint(9) {
    @include span-columns(3,9);

    &:nth-child(3n) {
      @include span-columns(3 omega,9);
    }
  }

  @include at-breakpoint(12) {
    @include span-columns(4,12);

    &:nth-child(3n) {
      @include span-columns(4 omega,12);
    }
  }
}
```